# random BOOLs in an efficient way for cocos2d

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, boolean, arc4random

According to [Steffen's post](http://cocos2d-central.com/topic/107-generating-random-numbers-in-an-efficient-way/page__view__findpost__p__447) this is an efficient way to generate random `BOOL`s in cocos2d

```
+(BOOL) getYesOrNo
{
   return (CCRANDOM_0_1() < 0.5f);
}
```

but how do I set a range for this? (e.g. 0 - 29 is the interval and 5 ones `BOOL` `=` `NO`, 25 ones `BOOL` `=` `YES` )

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can do something like this:

```
+(BOOL) getYesOrNo
{
    int tmp = (arc4random() % 30)+1;
    if(tmp % 5 == 0)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: This has modulo bias.

Comment: This solution produces false values more than true values, something like 1:10 for false value and that's because the percentage of making 5,10,15,20,25,30 is like 6/30 which make no sense at all

Answer (score 3):

You should use `arc4random` for random number generator.

```
#include <stdlib.h>

     u_int32_t
     arc4random(void);
```

> The arc4random() function uses the key stream generator employed by
>   the arc4 cipher, which uses 8*8 8 bit S-Boxes.  The S-Boxes can be
>   in about (2**1700) states.  **The arc4random() function returns pseudo-
>        random numbers in the range of 0 to (2****32)-1, and therefore has twice the range of rand and random.

```
-(BOOL)foo4random
{
u_int32_t randomNumber = (arc4random() % ((unsigned)RAND_MAX + 1));
if(randomNumber % 5 ==0)
    return YES;
return NO;

}
```

For more information on `arc4random` type

> man arc4random

on terminal.

Comment: You should use `arc4random_uniform` to prevent modulo bias, rather than reinventing the wheel

Answer (score 0):

The following code will generate a random bool value:

```
-(BOOL) randomBool
{
    int tmp = (arc4random() % 10);
    if(tmp % 2 == 0)
        return YES;
    return NO;
}
```